# calculate gridview column value in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want the third gridview column value to depend on the first column value.My code is as below :

```
  protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            GridViewRow item = e.Row;
            string selectSQL = "  SELECT fail,COUNT(*) AS 'Count' FROM Table WHERE Id =" + item.Cells[0].Text;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring.ToString());
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
            SqlDataReader reader;
            try
            {   con.Open();
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Read();

                if (reader["Count"].Equals("0"))
                    item.Cells[3].Text = "0";
                else
                    item.Cells[3].Text = reader["Count"].ToString();
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            { }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }


        }
    }
```

Edit :

```
GridViewRow item = e.Row;
            int myvar;
            Int32.TryParse(item.Cells[0].Text, out myvar);
            string selectSQL = "  SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Count' FROM Table WHERE Id=@myvar group by Id";
```

Can I do this ? No changes are being reflected in my code.

I tried debugging..the control enters the catch block..can't understand where am I going wrong

Comment: Do you wanna add new column to your gridview depends on your first column value? It is not exactly clear what you try to do. You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: You have an aggregate in your query without a `Group by`

Comment: Remove the catch and see what the actual error is.

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code-This is the exception in the line reader=cmd.ExecuteReader();

Answer (score 0):

You are calling database inside `RowDataBound`. Assume that you have thousands of rows, the database will be called thousands of times.

- Your first query is prone to `SQL injection`.

To solve these issues, first you have to get '`COUNTS`' for all the `Ids` and store it in local variable say a Dictionary. Then during `RowDataBound`, you can use the data from local variable.

The above scenario I have simulated with some sample data.

This is my local variable declared at `Page` level,

```
    private Dictionary<int, int> dictionaryIds = new Dictionary<int, int>();
```

This is my Page_Load method,

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            BindData();
        }
    }
```

And this is my `BindData` method,

```
    private void BindData()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring.ToString()))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table", connection))
            {
                adapter.Fill(ds);
            }
        }

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring.ToString()))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Count' FROM Table", connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    dictionaryIds.Add(Convert.ToInt32(reader["Id"].ToString()), Convert.ToInt32(reader["Count"].ToString()));
                }
                connection.Close();

            }
        }

        GridView2.DataSource = ds;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }
```

And this is my `RowDataBound` Method,

```
    protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            GridViewRow item = e.Row;
            int myvar;
            Int32.TryParse(item.Cells[0].Text, out myvar);

            if (dictionaryIds.ContainsKey(myvar))
                item.Cells[3].Text = dictionaryIds[myvar].ToString();
        }
    }
```

One more suggestion is, you have to move your data pulling logic into Data access layer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Selva,code optimisation is not a priority for me now..I agree it will be called many times but i have very few rows in my db.can u please refer this :

Comment: Please give me the link for the reference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987872/an-exception-of-type-system-invalidoperationexception-occurred-in-system-data